# Anonymously object call in PHP?

Tags: php, object, call, anonymous

I don't really need to store `DateTime` object. Would be possible to call `modify` anonymously? I've tried:

```
$passwordRequest->setExpire((new \DateTime())->modify('+12 hours'));
```

But can't get it to work. Am i asking for the moon?

Comment: This is currently under discussion for inclusion: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a limitation of PHP (I see it as one anyway) that you must call methods on a variable. In other words, what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: However, it is possible as of PHP 5.4 :)

Comment: Really?  Finally!  I've always missed being able to do this in PHP :).

Comment: Yep, see http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-11-11-1

Answer (score 2):

In this particular instance, you can use [`date_modify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-modify.php) instead like so:

```
passwordRequest->setExpire(date_modify(new DateTime(), '+12 hours'));
```

Testing:

```
var_dump(date_modify(new DateTime(), '+12 hours'));

object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2011-11-19 04:16:04"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(15) "America/Chicago"
}
```

As mentioned in the linked duplicate question, you cannot chain methods off a `new` instantiation.

Comment: Thank you. Not the right answer (php doesn't support chaining) but i'm going to use this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php), it looks like you can call modify() statically, but I tried it and it won't work. Looks like DateTime needs to be insantiated because the constructor takes a date.

```
// According to PHP looks like it should work, but doesn't
$passwordRequest->setExpire((DateTime::modify('+12 hours'));

// Notice I have to pass a date to the construct when I instantiate
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('+1 day');
```

A better implementation would be to make modify() static with two args, one for the date, and one for the time adjust, something like:

```
public static function modify($timeAdjust, $time = time())
```

Comment: All methods in the manual are listed as `ClassName::methodName`. This does not imply static method. Static methods have the `static` keyword in the method signature, cf. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Figured it was a naming convention, was worth a shot though.